# Difference between Any? and Any

Tags: swift

I know that `Any` means any instance of any kind of object. But does that include optional values?

What I have is this situation where I've got `data`:

```
var data = form.values() //this returns [String: Any?]
```

and I got a function taking in `[String : Any]`

```
func sendRequest(data: [AnyHashable : Any])
```

So when I pass `data` to this `sendRequest`, it's fine but the compiler issues a warning:

```
Expression implicitly coerced from Any? to Any.
```

I can see why. I'll just try to cast `[String: Any?]` to `[String: Any]`. When I do that:

```
var data = form.values() as! [String: Any]
```

I get a new warning saying:

```
Forced cast from [String: Any?] to [String: Any] always succeeds.
```

So yea, I feel completely lost. Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: Please read [Swift Language Guide: The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309). Optional values in dictionaries are nonsensical anyway.

Comment: vadian: Can you be more specific what in that chapter you're referring to?  I see no mention of "Any" in that chapter at all.

Answer (score 0):

`Any` holds anything (yes, even *Optionals*, but it isn't recommended).  `Any?` holds an *Optional* that has an associated value that can be anything or `nil`.  Swift warns you about implicitly converting `Any?` to `Any` because quite frankly it is a mess.  (It is difficult to know that an `Any` value is holding an *Optional* and yet you have to cast it in order to unwrap it).  You should probably consider unwrapping the values instead and creating a new dictionary.

In general, dictionaries that have an *Optional* type for the values are troublesome/nonsensical because the assignment of `nil` to a dictionary is used to remove an item from a dictionary.

If you have a function that returns `[String : Any?]` and want to pass it to another function that takes `[String : Any]`, I would suggest creating a new dictionary by unwrapping the values and throwing away the entries that have `nil` as the values.

For example:

```
let dict: [String : Any?] = ["name": "Fred", "age": 23, "nada": nil]

func foo(_ dict: [String : Any]) {
    for (key, value) in dict {
        print("\(key): \(value)")
    }
}

var newDict = [String : Any]()
dict.forEach { key, value in newDict[key] = value }

foo(newDict)
```

> ```
> name: Fred
> age: 23
> ```

In creating the `newDict`, we are able to take advantage of the fact that when assigning an *Optional* value to the value, the *unwrapped* value gets assigned.  If the value is `nil` then the entry simply isn't created.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting case.

According to [The Swift Language Guide: Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html):

> The Any type represents values of any type, including optional types.
>   Swift gives you a warning if you use an optional value where a value
>   of type Any is expected.

1. As you found, when you try to pass in a dictionary with optionals to your sendRequest method...

   ```
   sendRequest(data: data)
   ```

   ...you get a warning just to clarify that you may be unexpectedly passing in optionals:

   > Expression implicitly coerced from Any? to Any.
2. If you try to type cast it...

   ```
   sendRequest(data: data as [String: Any])
   ```

   ...you get the same warning:

   > Expression implicitly coerced from Any? to Any.

   This warning this time is a strange one, it's warning you that you're doing what you're actually trying to do! I suspect this might be a problem with the compiler.
3. As you saw, if you try to force downcast it...

   ```
   sendRequest(data: data as! [String: Any])
   ```

   ...you get this warning:

   > Forced cast from [String: Any?] to [String: Any] always succeeds.

   In general, to resolve this warning, you would instead use type casting (i.e. remove the !). However, as we've seen you get a warning if you type cast too.

You could live with the warning. Another long-winded solution to remove the warning could be to type cast first to Any, and then force downcast to [String: Any]:

```
sendRequest(data: vals as Any as! [String: Any])
```

Comment: That will avoid the compiler warnings, but every value will be wrapped in an *Optional* and it is unlikely that sendRequest is expecting that or is prepared to handle it.  I believe it is better to unwrap those values and create a new dictionary.

Comment: I can see your point, though I wasn't making any assumptions about sendRequest's implementation. But I agree with you that a dictionary value with an optional Any is "troublesome/nonsensical".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So is there a type in Swift that's like Any except that it CANNOT be nil/optional?