# Swift dictionary with mix types (optional and non-optional)

Tags: swift, dictionary, option-type

I have a struct that has a method to return a dictionary representation. The member variables were a combination of different types (String and Double?)

With the following code example, there would be a warning from Xcode (Expression implicitly coerced from 'Double?' to Any)

```
struct Record {
  let name: String
  let frequency: Double?

  init(name: String, frequency: Double?) {
    self.name = name
    self.frequency = frequency
  }

  func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
    return [
      "name": name,
      "frequency": frequency
    ]
  }
}
```

However if it was returning a type [String: Any?], the warning goes away:

```
struct Record {
  let name: String
  let frequency: Double?

  init(name: String, frequency: Double?) {
    self.name = name
    self.frequency = frequency
  }

  func toDictionary() -> [String: Any?] {
    return [
      "name": name,
      "frequency": frequency
    ]
  }
}
```

My question is: Is this correct? And if it is, can you point me to some Swift documentation that explains this?

If it isn't, what should it be?

== EDIT ==

The following works too:

```
struct Record {
  let name: String
  let frequency: Double?

  init(name: String, frequency: Double?) {
    self.name = name
    self.frequency = frequency
  }

  func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
    return [
      "name": name,
      "frequency": frequency as Any
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It might help to make the `struct` Codable, and encode it directly to `Data`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630244/difference-between-any-and-any

Comment: You can declare your dictionary type as Any and add optionals and non optionals anyway. You just need to explicitly coerce your `Double?` as `Any` -> `var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return ["name": name,"frequency": frequency as Any]
    }`

Comment: Note that there is no need to declare it as a method when you don't need to pass any parameter to it, just declare it as a computed property.   `init(name: String, frequency: Double?) {
    self.name = name
    self.frequency = frequency
  }`it is redundant when declaring a struct

Comment: `struct Record {
        let name: String
        let frequency: Double?
        var dictionary: [String: Any] {
            return ["name": name,"frequency": frequency as Any]
        }
    }`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597941/2303865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `frequency` to `Any` since the latter can hold *any* type. It is like casting instances of specific Swift type to the Objective-C id type. Eventually, you'll have to downcast objects of the type `Any` to a specific class to be able to call methods and access properties.

I would not recommend structuring data in your code using `Any`, or if you want to be specific `Any?` (when the object may or may not hold *some* value). That would be a sign of bad data-modeling.

From the [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html):

> *Any* can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.[...] Use *Any* and *AnyObject* **only** when you explicitly need the behavior and capabilities they provide. **It is always better to be specific** about the types you expect to work within your code.

*(emphasis is mine)*

Instead, use the `Data` type. And you would be able to decode `Record` or encode it from and into `Data`:

```
struct Record : Codable {
    let name: String
    let frequency: Double?

    init(name: String, frequency: Double?) {
        self.name = name
        self.frequency = frequency
    }

    init(data: Data) throws { 
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Record.self, from: data) 
    }

    func toData() -> Data {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else {
            fatalError("Could not encode Record into Data")
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
let record = Record(name: "Hello", frequency: 13.0)
let data = record.toData()

let decodedRecord = try Record(data: data)
print(decodedRecord.name)
print(decodedRecord.frequency ?? "No frequency")
```

Comment: Why not simply `self = record` ? Btw you should make your initialiser non fallible and make it propagate the error making it throws `init(_ data: Data) throws  {
       self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Record.self, from: data)
    }`

Comment: Why are you adding “from” it is pointless, the only case that would make sense would  be in a method  like `stride(from:to:)`. Just use IMO and to make it consistent with apple guidelines `init(data: Data)`

Comment: Sure, and you're more than welcome to edit the answer. Your valuable comments are very helpful to the community 

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend adding `Codable` conformance, and letting `JSONEncoder` do all the heavy lifting. If however you are constrained to the `toDictionary` approach, then I would advise against `[String:Any?]`, since that might result in undefined behaviour (try to print the dictionary for more details).

A possible solution for `toDictionary` is to use an array of tuples that gets converted to a dictionary:

```
func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
    let propsMap: [(String, Any?)] = [
        ("name", name),
        ("frequency", frequency)
    ]
    return propsMap.reduce(into: [String:Any]()) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
}
```

This way the nil properties simply don't receive entries in the output dictionary.

Comment: Why not simply explicitly coerce to Any only those types that are optionals?

Comment: @LeoDabus because the last sentence in my answer :)

Comment: Much easier to use the Dictionary initialiser `return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: [("name", name), ("frequency", frequency)] as! [(String,Any)] )`

Comment: @LeoDabus you should add an answer with that