# Why can't you assign an Optional to a variable of type `Any` without a warning?

Tags: swift, option-type

The following code compiles without warning:

### Version 1:

```
var anything: Any
anything = "woof"
```

Makes sense... Any is any type, value type or reference type.

However, if we create an optional variable like a `Double?`, this code throws a warning:

### Version 2:

```
var anything: Any
let aDouble: Double? = 3
anything =  aDouble
```

But this code does not throw a warning:

### Version 3:

```
enum AnEnum<T>: {
    case first
    case second (T)
}

var anEnum: AnEnum<String> = .first
anything = anEnum
```

You can rationalize that version 2 throws a warning because `Any` is not an `Optional` type, and `Double?` is an `Optional` type.  Trying to assign an Optional to a non-optional type is sort of a type mismatch.

However, under the covers, an `Optional` is an `enum` with a `.none` case, and with a `.some` case, where the `.some` case has an associated value. My version 3 uses an `enum`, `AnEnum`, that also has 2 cases, the second of which has an associated value. The `AnEnum` type is nearly identical to the Swift native `Optional` type.

Why is assigning an AnEnum value to `anything` ok, but assigning an Optional value to `anything` is not ok?

(I started to answer this question: [Swift dictionary with mix types (optional and non-optional)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504705/swift-dictionary-with-mix-types-optional-and-non-optional))

And then realized that I didn't really know the answer.

Answer (score 7):

`Optional` is more than just an enum. It's also an implicit promotion of every type. `Any` and `Optional` combine in weird ways that can be surprising. For example, `T?` is `Any`. `T??` is also `Any`. `Any` is `Any`, `Any?` is `Any`. `Any??` is also `Any`.

This creates a number of headaches, and subtle up-casts and down-casts make it very unclear what the optionality of an `Any` really is. For example.

```
var anything: Any = ""
let aDouble: Double? = 3
anything = aDouble as Any
let x = anything as? Double
```

What's `x` here? Well, `aDouble` is `Optional<Double>`, not `Double`, so `as? Double` should return `nil`. But it doesn't because *magic*. It returns `Optional(3)`. Which is frankly kind of weird (try to get the same thing with a version of MyOptional as an enum), but it would be really bad the other way. Consider:

```
let data: [String: Any] = ["aDouble": aDouble]
let y = data["aDouble"] as? Double
```

`y` is `Double?` here, not `Double??` because of optional coalescing. And thank goodness. But it's bizarre. And if you had generics involved with conformances based on `Optional`, this could get really confusing (and does; so many questions come up about that....) Now replace `Double` above with `Any` and it goes Inception on you really fast.

So the compiler is warning you that mixing `Any` with `Optional` is a bad idea and can lead to weird type results, and you definitely should be calling it out anytime you do it. (And maybe you should stop using `Any` because it is almost never the type you really mean anyway.)

To make it the most concrete example I can think of, consider:

```
var anything: Any = ""
let one: Int = 1
let maybeTwo: Int? = 2

anything = one
anything as? Int // fine

anything = maybeTwo
anything as? Int? // illegal (see below)
anything as? Int  // fine (but why? that's not what we put in.)
```

You'd think this would be parallel, but it isn't. You can't just pull out the type you put in when you throw Optionals into the mix.

BTW, interesting addendum, you can't downcast from `Any` to an `Optional` type.

```
let x = anything as? Double? // Illegal
```

That's really interesting, because `anything` *is* a `Double?`:

```
(lldb) p anything
(Any) $R4 = {
  payload_data_0 = 0x4008000000000000
  payload_data_1 = 0x0000000000000000
  payload_data_2 = 0x0000000000000000
  instance_type = Double?
}
```

So how can I tell the difference between "`anything` is `Double?` but nil" vs "`anything` is `String`"? You'd think you could test that, but I don't think you can, because none of this works consistently. Instead it tries to be convenient. But you can't push it too hard or all the seams will show.

Answer (score 7):

Quite simply, it's because Any is like a [Roach Motel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AA8X13A) for Optionals.

The Roach Motel is a cockroach trap whose motto is, "Roaches check in, but they don't check out." The same is true for Any and Optionals. You can put an Optional into an Any, but you can never get it out again.

To see what I mean, let's first put something *else* into an Any and get it out again:

```
let s : String = "howdy"
let any : Any = s
let s2 = any as! String
s2 // "howdy"
```

Now let's try that with an Optional:

```
let s : String? = "howdy"
let any : Any = s
let s2 = any as! String? // error
```

Ooops! You can't cast a nonOptional "down" to an Optional, so the original Optional is lost.

The thing *wrapped* by the Optional is *not* lost. You can still unwrap it:

```
let s : String? = "howdy"
let any : Any = s
let s2 = any as! String
s2 // "howdy"
```

But now `s2` is a String, not an Optional. The Optional is gone for good. You can't get it out. You can't find out that what was put into the Any *was* an Optional. It's gone.

So that's why putting an Optional into an Any always elicits a warning. The compiler is saying: "You can do this, but do you really understand what you're doing?" And if you do, there are ways to silence the warning (and the error message tells you what they are).

Comment: You can get the optional back out, though the compiler certainly doesn't make it easy. You have to convince it that you're casting to a non-optional value by e.g using a generic placeholder: https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/1a10df124d391cbd39a46a695dd7f8ba. The runtime will then happily do The Right Thing™.

Comment: @Hamish Okay that's hilarious.

Answer (score 6):

It has its own history.

Starting with this feature, in the era of Swift 3.

[SE-0116 Import Objective-C id as Swift Any type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0116-id-as-any.md)(So, called `id-as-Any` in the history of Swift, which is the worst thing in the history, in my opinion.)

(Until then, `Any` was not such a popular type in Swift programmers.)

It includes a fantastic new feature, **universal bridging conversion**, which guarantees literally `Any` values in Swift can be convertible to non-null `id` when bridging to Objective-C.

But this feature caused a huge number of disastrous tragedies, called `_SwiftValue`.

In the original conversion first introduced in Swift 3, `Optional<Double>` was converted to `_SwiftValue` regardless of whether it was `nil` or non-`nil`. It is completely useless in Objective-C world, almost all operations on `_SwiftValue` caused a crash, which could not have found till runtime, throwing away the goodness of strongly typed language.

So, Swift team needed to introduce a new feature immediately:

[SE-0140 Warn when Optional converts to Any, and bridge Optional As Its Payload Or NSNull](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0140-bridge-optional-to-nsnull.md)

Since this feature introduced in Swift 3.0.1, `nil`s are bridged to `NSNull` and non-`nil` values are bridged based on the unwrapped values.

The feature also includes **Warning when `Optional` is converted to `Any`** to avoid unintentional misuse of `Optional` to `Any`.

The warning you have described started at this time in the Swift history.

---

The behavior of `Optional` is backed by many *compiler magics* (so-called by Swift team members), for example, you cannot make use of simple if-let for other enum types, you cannot use Optional Chaining with your custom enums. Swift compiler treats `Optional` as a special thing than normal enums.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can have an `Optional<Any>`, by doing `Any?`. The compiler has no idea if you are expecting your `anything` type to be `nil` or `Optional.none` so it emits a warning to make sure you are aware of the situation.

Comment: But how is `Optional<Any>` fundamentally different from `AnEnum<Any>`?

Comment: Because `Optional<Any>` is identical to `Any?`, but `AnEnum<Any>` is not. The real question you should be asking yourself is, how is `Any?` any different than `Any`? :-)

Answer (score -1):

Here is how `AnEnum` different from `Optional`.

You can mimic `Optional` by implementing everything `Optional` does. However, what you create is another independent "Optional" that is not interoperable with Swift built-in `Optional`. For example, you can implement `ExpressibleByNilLiteral` so that you can assign `nil` to `AnEnum` which resolves to `.first`. Just like how `Optional` resolves `nil` to `Optional.none`

```
enum AnEnum<T> : ExpressibleByNilLiteral {

    case first
    case second (T)

    public init(nilLiteral: ())
    {
        self = .first
    }

}

var anEnum: AnEnum<String> = nil
var anything = anEnum
```

However, this `nil` will be DIFFERENT from the `nil` of `Optional`.

As suggested by the implementation, `Optional` does not use the value of `nil` directly, it just resolves `nil` literal to `Optional.none` which it actually stores.

Same as other `Enum`, `Optional.none` is just an unknown value (at least you couldn't guarantee it to equal any other values) since no `rawValue` is specified.

Your `nil` will be `AnEnum.first` while `Optional`'s `nil` will be `Optional.none`. `Optional.none` and `AnEnum.first` are two different unrelated Enum values. `Optional` won't consider `AnEnum.first` as `Optional.none` since they are different and the only way you get `Optional.none` is by assigning `nil` literal to `Optional`.

This explains why you can assign `AnEnum`, which you think is nearly identical to Swift native `Optional`, to `Any` with no problem but assigning an actual Swift native `Optional` to `Any` does causes problem. Because your custom "Optional" does not mean anything special other than an `Enum` to the compiler. The compiler only treats Swift native `Optional` specially even it is technically just an `Enum`.